# wsdl2java Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://***.***.***.***/***/***/***}objectFactory"

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java, apache-servicemix

This problem occur in newer version of servicemix(tested on 5.4 - cxf 3.0.2 and 5.3 - cxf 2.7.11) in older version 4.5.2 with cxf 2.6.8 everything works, webservices are created.

In our project we have a lot of different webservices generated by maven plugin wsdl2java in diffrent bundles. In servicemix 5.4 almost all webservices are down due to those errors, strange is that in previous servicemix 5.3 one of bundle is able to start without any modification in project.

In maven I tried use additional extraarg:

```
<extraarg>-autoNameResolution</extraarg>
<extraarg>-xjc-npa</extraarg>
```

But without any result

Stacktrace:

```
Unable to start blueprint container for bundle bundle-name1
    org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Unable to initialize bean .camelBlueprint.factory.camelContext
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:714)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:824)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)[:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)[:1.7.0_21]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:245)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstance(BlueprintRepository.java:230)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.create(BlueprintRepository.java:145)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.getComponentInstance(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:753)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.camel.blueprint.handler.CamelNamespaceHandler$CamelDependenciesFinder.process(CamelNamespaceHandler.java:863)[105:org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint:2.13.2]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.processProcessors(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:528)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.doRun(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:361)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:269)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:276)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.createContainer(BlueprintExtender.java:245)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintExtender.modifiedBundle(BlueprintExtender.java:235)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:500)[14:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.customizerModified(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:433)[14:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$AbstractTracked.track(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:725)[14:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$Tracked.bundleChanged(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:463)[14:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
        at org.apache.aries.util.tracker.hook.BundleHookBundleTracker$BundleEventHook.event(BundleHookBundleTracker.java:422)[14:org.apache.aries.util:1.1.0]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.invokeBundleEventHook(SecureAction.java:1127)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.createWhitelistFromHooks(EventDispatcher.java:696)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireBundleEvent(EventDispatcher.java:484)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireBundleEvent(Felix.java:4429)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2100)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1299)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)[org.apache.felix.framework-4.4.1.jar:]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)[:1.7.0_21]
    Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: Cannot lookup: routeBuilder from registry: org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintContainerRegistry@597012f0 with expected type: interface org.apache.camel.RoutesBuilder due: Error when instantiating bean ****CxfClient of class ***.***.***.***.***.***.***.***
        at org.apache.camel.impl.CompositeRegistry.lookupByNameAndType(CompositeRegistry.java:62)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.lookupByNameAndType(PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry.java:63)
        at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.lookup(CamelContextHelper.java:129)
        at org.apache.camel.model.RouteBuilderDefinition.createRoutes(RouteBuilderDefinition.java:70)
        at org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean.installRoutes(AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean.java:750)
        at org.apache.camel.core.xml.AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean.setupRoutes(AbstractCamelContextFactoryBean.java:311)
        at org.apache.camel.blueprint.CamelContextFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:304)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_21]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)[:1.7.0_21]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:297)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.invoke(BeanRecipe.java:958)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.runBeanProcInit(BeanRecipe.java:712)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        ... 30 more
    Caused by: org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.ComponentDefinitionException: Error when instantiating bean ****CxfClient of class ***.***.***.***.***.***.***.***
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstance(BeanRecipe.java:300)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:806)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)[:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)[:1.7.0_21]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.RefRecipe.internalCreate(RefRecipe.java:62)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:106)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstance(BeanRecipe.java:268)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:806)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)[:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)[:1.7.0_21]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.RefRecipe.internalCreate(RefRecipe.java:62)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:106)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperty(BeanRecipe.java:933)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:907)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.setProperties(BeanRecipe.java:888)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate2(BeanRecipe.java:820)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.internalCreate(BeanRecipe.java:787)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe$1.call(AbstractRecipe.java:79)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)[:1.7.0_21]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)[:1.7.0_21]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.di.AbstractRecipe.create(AbstractRecipe.java:88)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstances(BlueprintRepository.java:245)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.createInstance(BlueprintRepository.java:230)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintRepository.create(BlueprintRepository.java:145)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl.getComponentInstance(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:753)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.camel.blueprint.BlueprintContainerRegistry.lookupByNameAndType(BlueprintContainerRegistry.java:54)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.CompositeRegistry.lookupByNameAndType(CompositeRegistry.java:56)
        ... 43 more
    Caused by: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:341)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:86)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:490)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:704)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:550)
        at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:265)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:215)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:102)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:91)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:157)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:142)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[:1.7.0_21]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_21]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)[:1.7.0_21]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:297)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.invoke(BeanRecipe.java:958)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        at org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BeanRecipe.getInstance(BeanRecipe.java:298)[19:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.4.1]
        ... 75 more
    Caused by: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 2 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
    Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://***.***.***.***/***/***/***}objectFactory". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
        this problem is related to the following location:
            at ***.***.***.***.***.***.***.ObjectFactory
        this problem is related to the following location:
            at 1***.1***.1***.1***.1***.1***.1***.ObjectFactory
    Two classes have the same XML type name "{http://***.***.***.***/***/***/***}objectFactory". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
        this problem is related to the following location:
            at ***.***.***.***.***.***.***.ObjectFactory
        this problem is related to the following location:
            at 1***.1***.1***.1***.1***.ObjectFactory

        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:102)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:472)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:302)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1140)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:154)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:121)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor70.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.7.0_21]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)[:1.7.0_21]
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:222)[:2.4.0]
        at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:396)[:2.4.0]
        at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:656)[:2.4.0]
        at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:345)
        at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache$2.run(JAXBContextCache.java:343)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)[:1.7.0_21]
        at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.createContext(JAXBContextCache.java:343)
        at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.getCachedContextAndSchemas(JAXBContextCache.java:244)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createJAXBContextAndSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:484)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:339)
        ... 92 more
```

**EDIT**

I tried to downgrade cxf to 2.6.8 but i get the same errors so, I suppose the problem is somewhere else maybe in org.apache.aries.blueprint.core.

**EDIT 2**

I also tried to create one big bundle with all generated classes but problem is the same

Comment: Do the 2 xmltypes are from 2 different schema?

Comment: So, you are using cxf-codegen-plugin to generate client classes via maven?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was with wrong `<Import-Package>` in pom definition. We changed imports according to fuse documentation and everything start work properly.

```
 <Import-Package>
            javax.jws,
            javax.wsdl,
            javax.xml.bind,
            javax.xml.bind.annotation,
            javax.xml.namespace,
            javax.xml.ws,
            org.apache.cxf,
            org.apache.cxf.bus,
            org.apache.cxf.bus.spring,
            org.apache.cxf.bus.resource,
            org.apache.cxf.interceptor,
            org.apache.cxf.io, 
            org.apache.cxf.message, 
            org.apache.cxf.phase,
            org.apache.cxf.service,
            org.apache.cxf.service.model,
            org.apache.cxf.transport,
            org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing, 
            org.apache.cxf.ws.rm, 
            org.apache.cxf.ws.rm.v200702,
            org.apache.cxf.configuration.spring,
            org.apache.cxf.resource,
            org.apache.cxf.jaxws,
            org.springframework.beans.factory.config                
            *
        </Import-Package>
```

Answer (score 6):

In case you generate your ws-client code via the `cxf-codegen-plugin`, you could **separate** the package names of your ws-client bundles/parts with a specific configuration. I achieved something similar in one of my projects like so:

```
 ...
 <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-sources</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/gen</sourceRoot>
                    <wsdlOptions>
                        <wsdlOption>
                            <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/MyWSEndpoint1.wsdl</wsdl>
                            <extraargs>
                                <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                                <!--
                                <extraarg>-validate</extraarg>
                                -->
                                <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                <extraarg>com.acme.ws.jaxb.ns1</extraarg>
                                <extraarg>-wsdlLocation</extraarg>
                                <extraarg></extraarg>
                            </extraargs>
                        </wsdlOption>
                        <wsdlOption>
                            <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/MyWSEndpoint2.wsdl</wsdl>
                            <extraargs>
                                <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                                <!--
                                <extraarg>-validate</extraarg>
                                -->
                                <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                <extraarg>com.acme.ws.jaxb.ns2</extraarg>
                                <extraarg>-wsdlLocation</extraarg>
                                <extraarg></extraarg>
                            </extraargs>
                        </wsdlOption>
                    </wsdlOptions>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
 </plugin>          
 ...
```

Thus, "individual" packages for each ws-client specific `{http://***.***.***.***/***/***/***}objectFactory` should be generated which might help to avoid conflicts during the code generation phase. Thereby, at runtime, no NameSpace-related issues should be blocking you.

Keep in mind that `com.acme.ws.jaxb.ns1` and `com.acme.ws.jaxb.ns2` are only suggestions and that you could use whatever seems valid for your project there.

See also [Apache CXF - WSDL to Java](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html)

> -p [ wsdl-namespace= ] PackageName
>
> Specifies zero, or more, package names to use for the generated code. Optionally > specifies the WSDL namespace to package name mapping.

Comments welcome.

Comment: Hi, already in our project we use arg -p [ wsdl-namespace= ] PackageName. Main question is why in different cxf those generated class are working in different way.

Comment: are they separated to be different in each module?

Comment: It's not that obvious for others when they see masked packages ... ;)